# Linear algebra Upper Triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question regarding upper triangular matrix.

I know that if AB is upper triangular then the |AB| equals to the diagnoal multiplication, but It doesn't seem to help me here.

If AB is upper triangular and non-singular then A and B both upper triangular?

Notice that A and B are both square.

I can't choose AB = 0 becuase its signular....

Comment: Are $A,B$ square?

Comment: Yes they are both square matrices

Comment: Never mind, didn't read the question properly...

Answer (score 1):

No, $A$ and $B$ does not necessarily have to be upper triangle. For example,
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Wow so simple......... Thank you very much!

Comment: I have one more question to ask but I don't want to open mass of questions. can I assign it here?

Comment: @Guy: What is it?

Comment: I was wondering about one adjugate matrix property.

I know that If $A$ is symmetric so is $adj(A)$.

I was thinking to myself, is the opposite direction is also TRUE?

If $adj(A)$ is symmetric then $A$ is symmetric ?

Thank you.

Comment: @wj32 see above. about the adjugate matrix.

Comment: @Guy: Take a $3 \times 3$ matrix with a 1 in the upper-right corner (or anywhere).

Comment: damn missed you answer till now. Thank you very much !